# Can the jQuery Mobile loading spinner be used over specific page elements?

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm writing an app designed for a tablet in which I need to load data every time a row in a table is selected. When a row is selected, I want to position the spinner over the div where the new data will be loaded.

Is this possible, or do I need to block the whole page or bring in something like BlockUI?

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.2.0 Alpha.

Thanks!

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. The loader is still just centered on the page. Think an iPad Split View and I want to just have the loader over the right pane.

Comment: I take that back, I see what your doing. Let me give it a shot.

Answer (score 3):

Like this ???

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/MsbqT/)

**jQuery:**

```
function loadData(id) {
    
    var btnID = id;
    $.ajax({
        
        url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/akhurshid/g2tD5/show/",       
       
           beforeSend: function() {
            $('.loader').html('<img src="http://cdn.nirmaltv.com/images/generatorphp-thumb.gif" alt="Wait" />');
           },
              
           success: function(data) {           
               $('.loader').fadeTo('fast','0.0');
               $('#' + btnID).fadeTo('fast','0.0'); 
            
                var htmlData = $('.result').html(data).hide().css('opacity','0');
            
                $(htmlData).fadeTo('fast','1.0');                                 
           }
    });
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div class="result"></div>
    <button id="load-btn" onclick="loadData(this.id);">Load Data Here</button>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    background: #ccc;
}

.loader{
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/UNmEh/

JS

```
// show the loader
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

// Move the loader left 30 pixels
$('div.ui-loader').attr('style','left:30px;'); ​
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="placeholder-page">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible = true;

$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("b", "please wait...");
```